# How to get xpath for dynamic iframe?

Tags: javascript, java, xpath, iframe, web-applications

[image]

Hello,
In the below application, the CVV is within an iframe(as shown in the attached screenshot) and the iframe xpath is dynamic in nature. I tried to use the below xpath, but it fails as the digits keeps changing. Could u please help on how to handle this dynamic iframe xpath?

//iframe[@id='cardinal-stepUpIframe-1586884117320']

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors  Use the starts with CSS selector

Comment: Or `#stepUpView > div > iframe`

Comment: @Taplar but the iframe number is dynamic.

Comment: Both the start with selector from my first comment, and my second comment, do not use the number at all.

Comment: @Taplar- I tried the below xpath - //iframe[contains(@id,'cardinal-stepUpIframe')]. hope it works in my automation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the start with in xpath or css as shown below.

**Xpath**

```
//iframe[starts-with(@id,'cardinal-stepUpIframe-')]
```

**CSS:**

```
iframe[id^='cardinal-stepUpIframe-']
```